# ArCade Expression in Pop-Up- change color based on attribute

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I have a layer with a "Completed" field with 4 unique values.
- design phase
- future year
- under construction
- completed

in my pop-up configs I have "Status: {Completed}"

How can I use Arcade to change the color of the status value text based on its value?

eg. completed = green
under construction = orange, 
design phase black
future years light grey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Answer was to create a specific Arcade Expression per "Value" that I wanted and identify each expression in the pop-up config with a different color text.

Expression 0: `IIf($feature.status=='completed', 'completed', '')`

Expression 1: `IIf($feature.status=='under construction’, 'under construction', '')`
Expression 2: `IIf($feature.status=='in design', 'in design', '')`

Add each expression in pop-up

Status: {expression/expr0}{expression/expr1}{expression/exp2}

assign each of those expression a unique color within the pop-up config manager

Answer (score 1):

One slight difference I used was in passing the field value back into the expression, rather than defining it as 'string':

```
IIf($feature.status=='under construction’, $feature.status, '')
IIf($feature.status=='completed’, $feature.status, '')
IIf($feature.status=='in design’, $feature.status, '')
```

This works really well for non-string values as well, ex. $feature.speed>50, $feature.speed<60.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

Bring Colors From Your Map Into Your Pop-up Using Arcade

https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/bring-colors-from-your-map-into-your-pop-up-using-arcade/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/216883)